# How to open a folder with Atom text editor? (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thunar, atom

When I right click on a folder either on my desktop or in thunar I want an option to open the folder with atom or really some other programs as well such as a picture/music/media program. I've done this fairly easily before in cinnamon (on arch if it matters) and in windows.

Comment: What do you mean by "open the folder with Atom"? I am not sure how you would expect to open an entire directory with a single program with a right click. Atom is a text editor, so you can't expect to open music or most types of media other than text. There _may_ be a picture viewer package for Atom, but I am not sure.

Comment: Most text editors (in my experience anyway) accept multiple arguments and will open all of the files in tabs or the argument list or what have you. I assume that's what's being suggested.

Comment: @SorenBjornstad In the terminal, sure. I am not sure about right-clicking a folder of various things in it though.

Comment: I think they want the option to **Open folder** or **Open directory** from the context/ right-click menu, including "Open with Atom" and "Open with [image viewer]" etc? Maybe just use "Open with..." option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open **Thunar**, go to **Edit** and **Configure custom actions.**

From there you will be able to add any options you'd like, such as to "Open with Atom" or anything else. I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry about the slightly poor description and probably simple question, I'm still fairly new to xfce.

Comment: Absolutely! I love XFCE, I always come back to it :) I'm sorry I wasn't more detailed; I realized after that post that I could've explained how to make some custom actions, but let me know if you need help, I'm here. We're all here! Cheers.